# Apply keyframeable rotation, positioning, scale and skew animation on video/image using mlt framework

Tags: qt, skew, video-editing, mlt

I am trying to achieve keyframeable scale, position, rotation(rotation along specific point), skew and opacity animation using mlt framework.

I investigated in mlt and found three filters:- frei0r.c0rner, affine, qtblend.
But these all three filter has his own limitation. For example

1. With frei0r.c0rner, I can achieve position, skew and scale animation
   but not rotation.
2. With qtblend, I can achieve scale, position, rotation(rotation along
   top left and centre point), skew and opacity animation but not skew
   and rotation along specific point.
3. With affine, I can achieve rotation(along corner and centre),
   positioning, scale and opacity animation but not skew and rotation
   along specific point.

So I tried combining these filter but not getting desired result as each filter consider whole screen and apply filter on whole screen, due to which its not giving expected result. I tried different parameters but it's not working.

I decided to edit mlt filter. I am editing QTBlend filter. I am able to achieve rotation along arbitrary point.

I am facing challenge in achieving skewness. In QTransform there is one function shear which provide sense of skew, but

1. I am not able to understand what will be the parameter value. Because we provide skew in angle.
2. How to move top left and top right corner to have skew in that direction also.